# Assembly x86 How do I input/output a string

Tags: assembly, x86, dos

Completely new to assembly language, trying to learn. I'm trying to make a program that prints out a message that I input. Here's my code:

```
.model small
.stack 100h

.data

    msg db  20

.code

start:

    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    mov ah, 0ah
    mov dx, offset msg
    int 21h

    lea dx, msg
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h


end start
```

After I run this program and input a string it prints out random characters and such could someone tell me what am I doing wrong?
Thank you

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24819739/3512216

Comment: You didn't initialize `msg`, why?

Comment: You're only printing a space - that's unusual and ineffective. You're also not finishing the string with a `$` which is necessary for a DOS print function.

Comment: @Rafael: `db 20` is a single byte with value `20`.  Were you thinking of NASM `resb 20` or something?  In MASM that would be `db 20 dup(?)`.  So anyway, it's initialized, but there's no terminator unless there happens to be a 0 byte later in the `.data` section.

Comment: @PeterCordes ah, yes, that is exactly what I was thinking :facepalm:.

Comment: Actually, does `ah=0ah` take the first byte as a buffer length?  Then it might be overwriting code with data, if this is a `.com` with the data section right next to code.

Comment: @PeterCordes: `.model small` indicates an .exe program. A .com program needs `.model tiny`.

Comment: Unless of course it was assembled in the small model and then converted to a COM file with exe2bin